# Creating PL/SQL block to retrieve specific data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i need to retrieve Donor first and last name, email and pledge amount for the highest pledge amount. If the pledge is closed it has to display a thank you note if not display hurry up. Display using this format: Donor Name, Pledge Amount, email, and the message.
This is the code that i wrote so far.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

pledge_amount     DD_PLEDGE.PLEDGEAMT%type;
first_name        DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%type;
last_name         DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%type;
email_address     DD_DONOR.EMAIL%type;
id_status         DD_PLEDGE.IDSTATUS%type;
display_msg CHAR(20);

BEGIN
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PLEDGEAMT, IDSTATUS
INTO first_name, last_name, email_address, pledge_amount, id_status
FROM DD_PLEDGE, DD_DONOR
where DD_PLEDGE.IDDONOR = DD_DONOR.IDDONOR
and DD_PLEDGE.IDDONOR = max(pledgeamt)
Group BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PLEDGEAMT, IDSTATUS;
IF id_status = '40' THEN
display_msg = Thank You;
ELSE
display_msg = Hurry Up;
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
' First Name ' || first_name
||' Last Name ' || last_name
||' Pledge Amount: ' || pledge_amount
||' Email ' || email_address
||' MSG ' || display_msg
);

end;
```

After the code i run into the following issues

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 15, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 18, column 13:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Why do you have a group by clause and no aggregate function?

Comment: This is the first time in writing in PL/SQL i based this on the other works i have seen so i dont even know if i need group by clause or what is aggregate function.

Comment: you cant use this `max(pledgeamt)` directly , you need to write subquuery. Please provide structure of both table so that we can help you

Comment: Use this `SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PLEDGEAMT, IDSTATUS
INTO first_name, last_name, email_address, pledge_amount, id_status
FROM DD_PLEDGE, DD_DONOR
where DD_PLEDGE.IDDONOR = DD_DONOR.IDDONOR
and DD_PLEDGE.IDDONOR = (select max(pledgeamt) from DD_PLEDGE);` also remove `group by ` no need.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE

pledge_amount     DD_PLEDGE.PLEDGEAMT%type;
first_name        DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%type;
last_name         DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%type;
email_address     DD_DONOR.EMAIL%type;
id_status         DD_PLEDGE.IDSTATUS%type;
display_msg CHAR(20);
max_amount        DD_PLEDGE.PLEDGEAMT%type;

BEGIN

select max(pledgeamt) into max_amount from DD_DONOR;

SELECT dd.FIRSTNAME, dd.LASTNAME, dd.EMAIL, dp.PLEDGEAMT, dp.IDSTATUS 
INTO first_name, last_name, email_address, pledge_amount, id_status
FROM DD_PLEDGE dp , DD_DONOR dd
where dp.IDDONOR = dd.IDDONOR
and dp.IDDONOR = max_amount;

IF id_status = '40' THEN
display_msg = Thank You;
ELSE
display_msg = Hurry Up;
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
' First Name ' || first_name
||' Last Name ' || last_name
||' Pledge Amount: ' || pledge_amount
||' Email ' || email_address
||' MSG ' || display_msg
);

end;
```

You didn't you any aggregate function so need of group by function.

For MAX() in where clause you have to use separate query. Use also can user cursor if you want to use this query again and again in future.

**One important thing When you use join and displays column from both the tables you have to append table name/table object before the name of column**

Comment: dp.IDDONOR = (select max(pledgeamt) from DD_DONOR) is wrong.

Comment: No, still not correct.  How is IDDONOR, an ID comparable against a dollar amount?

Comment: @OldProgrammer : I just help him to remove the error which is because of `MAX()`. Now he will able to execute PL/SQL block , we cant assure about logically correct. @Andre Ilnytskyy : You have to provide your table structure to help you further in this question.